# Is the "developing" tag really necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing) really necessary? Is it helpful at all?

I can understand that using [developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing) together [modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules) would make clear that the question is not about which module to use to accomplish a specific task, but how implementing the code for a module. Is it how the tag is used by other users?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is very helpful.

I am an experienced Drupal-PHP developer and want to help people with specific questions on module and php-development.

These questions are buried deep in the (IMHO) boring<sup>[*]</sup> "what-module-to-use", hence I steer towards the [developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing) tag always first.

That said, I personally think we might rename it to the more appropriate [development](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development).

<sup>[*]</sup> I, as answerer, steer free of all the "you should use module Y and Z". I find these questions not only boring, but personally think that, most of the time, pulling in three modules to get something simple is just the Plain Wrong Approach.

Comment: The problem in most of the cases, the answer involves code, as there are some questions for which the OP accepts also an answer that reports the code to use, if there isn't really a module to use. I think that is the only possible answer, as saying "no, there isn't a module for that" is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Still, questions that are clearly about programming should be tagged as such. To make them filterable, distinguisable and highlighted for people like me, who want to help learn people Develop/program Drupal.

Comment: If there would be such a distinct separation between questions about developing, and not, it would be possible. As general rule, a tag that is applicable to almost all the questions is not helpful; at the end, it would not filter anything, if it used for 99% of the questions.

Comment: What about "programming" as tag then?

Comment: What if the no-code-here-please-i-am-still-new-to-php were tagged instead? We could promote the usage of a "site-building" tag.

Comment: @barraponto It is not necessary a tag for that; the OP should make that clear. Who answers can still report how to do it writing a custom module, though; it is up to the OP accepting, or not the answer.

Comment: Note that I, as a Drupal Programmer follow the "developing" (or development or programming tags) to answer Programming questions. I am not interested in answering yet-another-what-views-addon-to-use question. If this tag drops, there is no way for me to find the questions I want to answer. Fine, if that is the choice in this community. But that means that programmers like me have little to do here. Sorry. And goodbye then :)